# Clicking a link that's behind a div?

Tags: css, positioning, layer

I'm not sure the title adequately describes the problem I've found myself with...

Basically, I'm in the process of redesigning my website and one of the issues I've run into is that on the gallery view of my portfolio you get a grid of images for pieces of my work inside a frame.

When you hover over the frame the image is hidden and the title, client, category and year are shown.

However, there *should* be a link that sits over everything and is clickable. However, the above information sits over the image, even though it's below it in the markup.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the above information residing in a DIV that is positioned absolutely (which allows it to sit in the top of the frame and is thus necessary).

What I would like to achieve is to have the entire frame be clickable when you hover over it, even the area covered by the DIV. Please let me know if this is unclear...

You can see the site in action here: http://www.designbyadmiral.com/

I'm sure that will help clear some things up.

Comment: This is not related to your question, sorry: But doesn't this link to your website improve your page rank on google drastically? And what is stackoverflow's take on this?

Comment: @anderstornvig actually no, SO uses nofollow (rel="nofollow").

Comment: Just so everyone knows the portfolio rollovers are not powered by any javascript and if I have to choose between a less semantic markup in order to avoid javascript on this part of the site I will. I was just hoping there was a way for me to have both the functionality and the semantic markup in a way that was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this done, you'll probably need to modify a lot of code (since I made a workaround and couldn't find any simply solution). If you don't have any special reason to use an anchor (other than the main one: use the damm anchors as links!) the fallowing snippet should work:

```
$(".project").each(function(){
    var url = $(this).children('.project-link').attr('href');
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $(this).click(function(){
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using jQuery plugins for all UI stuff, so it may be hard to customize the behavior.

The simplest thing to do would be to add a click event to the overlaying div which uses the href of the underlying link to navigate to another page:

```
$("#topdiv").click(function() { 
   window.location = $("#originallink").attr("href"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm achieving the desired result with this markup, and no javascript :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
ul { list-style: none }
li { float: left }
li a { display: block; position: relative; text-decoration: none; color: #5e5d56; }
li a img, li a div { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; margin: 13px; border: none; }
li a img { z-index: 2; }
li a:hover img { display: none }
li a div { background: #b8b7af; padding: 20px; z-index: 1; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.designbyadmiral.com/project/maclure-library-site-redesign" style="width:458px;height:523px">
            <img width="432" height="497" alt="Maclure Library site redesign screenshot" src="http://www.designbyadmiral.com/image/1/432/0/uploads/maclure-2-screenshot-1.jpeg"/>
            <div class="project-information">
        <h3>Maclure Library Site Redesign</h3>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Client</dt>
                    <dd>Maclure Library</dd>
                    <dt>Year</dt>
                    <dd>2009</dd>
                    <dt>Category</dt>
                    <dd>Web</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.designbyadmiral.com/project/maclure-library-site-redesign" style="width:458px;height:499px">
            <img width="432" height="473" alt="Infamy homepage screenshot" src="http://www.designbyadmiral.com/image/1/432/0/uploads/infamy-website-1-homepage.jpeg"/>
            <div class="project-information">
        <h3>Infamy Website Design and Development</h3>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Client</dt>
                    <dd>Schadenfreude Productions Ltd.</dd>
                    <dt>Year</dt>
                    <dd>2008</dd>
                    <dt>Category</dt>
                    <dd>Web</dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why it doesn't work on your page ; but I don't think that you should have to use javascript for such a simple task.

Comment: I might resort to doing something like this but the reason I hadn't yet is because you can't have a DIV inside an anchor tag, just as you can't have an H3 or DL inside an anchor tag. This was the first solution I tried.